# Using timers to execute recurring event

Tags: c#

I am new to C# and I am currently using it to control a vehicle. I want to automate the vehicle's movement between 2 locations continuously moving back and forth.

My current way of doing it uses timers. The part of my code that pertains to this function is listed below:

```
 private void button19_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //Loop button enables timer3 to start
    {
        timer3.Enabled = true;
        timer3.Interval = 401;
        timer3.Start();

        //sets vehicle mode to max speed 
        send_ok_flags |= 0x02; 
        sersendbuf[2] = 0x06;
        sersendbuf[3] = 0x13;
        sersendbuf[4] = 0x02;
        sersendbuf[5] = 0x00;
    }   

    private void button20_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //stops timer 3
    {
        timer3.Stop(); 
        timer3.Enabled = false;
    }

    private void timer3_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) //timer event
    {
        Int32.TryParse(maskedTextBox15.Text, out cDest);
        if (Math.Abs(cDest - dest) < 300) //close to target destination, go back to starting
        {
            button1.PerformClick();           
            counter++;
        }

        if (Math.Abs(cDest - sDest) < 300) //close to starting destination, go towards target 
        {
            send_ok_flags |= 0x02;
            byte[] s1buf = { 0xAB, 0xBA, 0x08, 0x12, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 };
            s1buf[4] = (byte)sDest;
            sDest >>= 8;
            s1buf[5] = (byte)sDest;
            sDest >>= 8;
            s1buf[6] = (byte)sDest;
            sDest >>= 8;
            s1buf[7] = (byte)sDest;
            s1buf.CopyTo(sersendbuf, 0);
            counter++;
        }

        label46.Text = counter.ToString();
        label47.Text = cDest.ToString();
        label48.Text = dest.ToString();
    }
```

The gist of how the code works is that button 19 starts the continuous travel operation between 2 points, button 20 ends the operation. timer3_Tick is the event that occurs every 401ms which compares the current position value, target position value, and starting position value to determine if the vehicle is close to point A (starting position) or point B (target position) and then executes the appropriate actions to move forward or backwards.

The position values that timer3_tick compares are sampled from the micro-controller on the vehicle every 201ms using another timer, timer 1.

I am getting unreliable operations and wanted to know if there is another method in C# to automate the vehicle travel without the use of timers?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "unreliable operations"?  Also, it's good to note that not all timers are created equal.  A System.Threading.Timer will work on it's own thread Asynchronously.  However, a System.Windows.Forms.Timer will work within the thread of the UI for the Form.  In either case, you probably want to make sure that subsequent calls to the loopMotion(x) functions occur in the correct order.  I don't think there is anything wrong with using a timer here, just need to make sure the functions occur in the correct sequence.

Comment: By unreliable operations I mean when I press the button for the vehicle to travel continuously sometimes it does, sometimes it doesn't, sometimes it travels halfway, sometimes it travels the full distance etc. 

I think it's a timer issue because when I disabled timer 3 I get updated current position values but when I enable it I don't. The operation logic depends on the current position values which could explain why I am getting unreliable operations. I think timer 3 might be interfering with my timer that controls the data communication between the vehicle and the Window's app.

Comment: You code seems to have multiple recursive loops and possibly more depending on what 'button1' and 'radioButton2' click events do.  That might be calling the 'move code' erratically.  Also, depending on how fast the vehicle moves, the timer may fire before the vehicle moves out of the <250 range and this re-invoking the 'move code' again.  I suggest stopping the timer until the move code completes and then restarting it.  Also consider changing the recursive calls to a while loop.  Personally I would encapsulate the move code into a class and also thread it to prevent locking the GUI.

Comment: I updated the code so that there is no nested loops, but it is still not working. I don't think I want to use a while loop because I believe that would stop all other events until the while loop is completed. 

The other problem I have is that when I press button 20, it stops the timer, but when I press button 19 again the timer doesn't start as it should. It starts on the initial button 19 click but does not after button is 20 is clicked. Technically, the way that it is written, shouldn't I be able to toggle the timer on and off?

Comment: Giving your controls and variables meaningful names may go a long way to reduce confusion.

Comment: Update: I isolated the problem, the logic works but the problem is that button1.PerformClick() does not work...any thoughts?

Thanks!